# Spring MVC can not fetch JSON value

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring mvc I have a **mytable.json** file.

I want to fetch that json file data and then want to add to **model.addAttribute().**

**mytable.json**

```
{"name1":["place1.1","place1.2"],
  "name2":["place2.1","place1.2"] 
...........
.........}
```

I want to fetch the **names** with their corresponding **citylist**.

Ex:

name1=place1.1,place1.2

so,I have done:--

```
     try {           

            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

             ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("file/mytable.json").getFile());
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(file));

            Iterator<String> keys = obj.values().iterator();

            while( keys.hasNext() ) 
            {
                String key = (String)keys.next();
                if ( obj.get(key) instanceof JSONObject )
                {
                    model.addAttribute("key", key);


                }

            }           


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I am getting error:

Unexpected character (�) at position 0.

in this line :

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(file));
```

why??Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you check whether ```servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/mytable.json")``` get you the right path?

Comment: I have edited my question..and this is the right path..

Comment: What JSON Parser are you using? I am able to parse with ```org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser```

Comment: I am also using this

Comment: Can you just try recreating the file file/mytable.json? File encoding may have an issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();` is expecting a JSON String, not a **.json file**. hence the **Unexpected character....** error.

You can `InputStreamReader`:

```
jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file/mytable.json")));
```